# Remarks in changes package with RevTex

Tags: marginpar, revtex, marginnote, changes

I can't seem to make the `remark` option from the `changes` package in combination with RevTeX.

In this example, I can "add" text but I cannot add a remark without obtaining an error of type:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \not \equal 
                       {\Changes@added@id }{\@empty }
l.19 text \added[remark={Comment}]{tax}
                                        ddd
```

**Is there a workaround for this?**

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[prb,11pt]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{changes}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
text \added[remark={Comment}]{tax} ddd

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, from other examples, adding a "sidenote" package solves the problem:

```
\usepackage[footnote=true]{snotez}
```

If there is a better solution, it will be welcome.